# can I browse installed certificates on android phone?

Tags: android, certificate

I found [how to](http://groups.google.com/group/android-security-discuss/browse_thread/thread/11f502ccd41ff5d3) pull cacerts.bks file from phone's sytem/etc/security folder and see the list of installed certificates using keytool.
But can I browse them somehow on a phone itself?

Comment: Can anyone tell me why I am not seeing "security certificates" item in 'WiFi settings | Advanced' menu?

Answer (score 0):

As for cd-ing in a directory structure, etc, I'm not sure. I needed to pull a list up of certificates, and (in addition to this question) I found [this source](https://motorola-enterprise.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/63743/related/1/session/L2F2LzEvdGltZS8xNDA0MjQzODM4L3NpZC9VT0R3Z2RZbA%3D%3D) that mentions how to show a list of installed certificates on an older version of Android. On my phone (running 4.4.2), the steps are slightly different:

1. Settings
2. Security
3. Trusted credentials

and a list of trusted CA certificates is displayed.